# HTML avoid coping blocks of code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, single-page-application

I trying to learn web technologies (HTML, JS, angular, etc. what is needed to create pages). For practice I downloaded some kind of website template and noticed that there is a lot of same code in different `html` files(pages).

For example we have pages: login,main,about. Each of this page has same `<header/>` and `<footer>` and difference is only in `<section/>` between them.

So is it possible to have such structure: Main page with `header` and `footer` and on menu click changes only section between them? It will look like single page app.

As I use angularjs I know that there is such attribute as a `ng-view` but I am not sure if it will be suitable here, when, lets call, inner pages have this attribute inside also. (I tried I got `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` not sure probably some kind of infinitive loop appeared).

So what would be best solution in particular situation, I am not sure that my suggested structure is good, but I do not want to have same blocks of code in each page or it should be in HTML?

I use HTML, angular, JS, bootsrap for theme.

**Examle**

I copied two pages as example to `plunker`, so As you can see a lot of code is same, so I want to show `login.html` inside `index.html` (line: 172), but in `login.html` I also have `ng-view` (line:177). Maybe someone can with small code sample can show me how it is made?
http://plnkr.co/edit/iJrg2FJgwr9xxKTWMouX?p=preview

Comment: Do you have any code for us to play with?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible with AngularJs, and in fact very easy using `ng-view` or `ui-view` (from ui-router) .

Depending on your level of expertise I would suggest taking a look at [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which has all the ng-router functionalities and even more.

Answer (score 0):

A simple routing setup for an app using **ngRoute** would be something like this.

```js
angular.module('stack-app', ['ngRoute']);
// set up the views at configure time
angular.module('stack-app').configure(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', { // http://website.com/view1
      controller: 'View1Controller', // the controller for view1
      templateUrl: 'view1.html' // this is a partial view 
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/view2', { // http://website.com/view2
      controller: 'View2Controller', // controller for view 2
      template: '<div>inline template should do just fine</div>'
    });

   $routeProvider.otherwise('/view1'); // http://website.com/anythingelse points to /view1
  }
]);

angular.module('stack-app').controller('StackMainController', function() {});

angular.module('stack-app').controller('View1Controller', function() {});
angular.module('stack-app').controller('View2Controller', function() {});
```

**index.html** here you would put the common parts, headers etc.

```html
<html ng-app="stack-app">

<body ng-controller="StackMainController">
  <!-- this will be replaced by the partial views -->
  <ng-view></ng-view> 
</body>

</html>
```

You will have to configure whatever server you are using to serve **index.html** when receiving requests for **/view1** or **/view2**.
Also don't forget to import the **angular-route.js** file in your project.

You can also have other modules register routes in their own configure method, there's no need to have a central config.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ui-router` to achieve this. You can define your states and templates using ui-router. Then for each state you can inject your views into sections marked as `ui-view` in your templates. Check out the example.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router"]);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: '/',
      template: 'Main Page'
    })
    .state('list1', {
      url: 'list1',
      template: '<div>List1 {{test}}</div>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.test = "List 1";
      }
    })
    .state('list2', {
      url: 'list2',
      template: '<div>List2 {{test}}</div>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.test = "List 2";
      }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body>
  <div><a ui-sref="main">Header</a> <a ui-sref="list1">List1</a>  <a ui-sref="list2">List2</a>
  </div>
  <div ui-view=""></div>
  <div>Footer</div>

</body>

</html>
```